# Mensa Norway Test Inconsistent Exercise

Tags: pattern

Today I did the Mensa IQ test at http://test.mensa.no and I found something really strange regarding the Exercise 34. There is already a thread regarding it ([Mensa web test question #34](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/mensa-web-test-question-34)), and it gives 2 solutions, but I also found an old you tube video with answers to the test, https://youtu.be/yPNCtfOjqfA?t=294

[image]

If you compare the 2 images you will notice that the answers are different; at the end of the video the score is 145, the maximum possible score, using the option 3 at exercise 34. 
I did the test multiple times, using all the correct answers for the other exercises and changing only the options of the n°34: now, to obtain the maximum score of 145, you have to select the answer 5; if you select the answer 3 (that was previously correct) you obtain 143 as score.

I know that this isn't a real question but I wanted to point this inconsistency; I used to do a lot of puzzles and tests a long time ago, and I was always curious regarding how are iq test arranged.