# Mensa IQ test question answer?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

What is the missing piece and why?

[image: IQ test matrix]

I think it is pretty interesting but I cannot find any pattern. Do you have any idea?

Comment: looks like https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/mensa-web-test-question-34

Comment: Looks like the old tests as mentioned above, only the correct answer here seems to be mirrored around the vertical axis. Are we being trolled?